# Oracle rownum function

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

How I can get rownum in oracle over order by name? 
i.e In SQL I have a query

```
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FIRSTNAME) SRL

  FROM   
    [SECURITY].[USERS]

  ORDER BY 
    FIRSTNAME
```

How will it be in Oracle?

Comment: Remove the non-standard square brackets and the syntax is fine for Oracle (and a lot of other standard compliant DBMS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FIRSTNAME)SRL FROM USERS
```

Comment: Yes, PARTITION BY is optional.

Answer (score -2):

In Oracle, `ROWNUM` refers to the current record *in the result set* (which should be ordered).

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS SRL
FROM USERS
ORDER BY FIRSTNAME
```

**EDIT: THIS IS WRONG. ROWNUM is assigned BEFORE ordering.**

Comment: Yes, but ROW_NUMBER is something else

Comment: True.  It is a window function. However, a window function is not much use if you are not partitioning the result set, and having a window function with one partition is pretty similar to just using ROWNUM, I believe. ROWNUM is for Oracle, I am not sure what the equivalent for SQL Server is.

Comment: Incorrect. ROWNUM is a pseudocolumn that resolves to 1 for the first row returned, 2 for the next, and so on - but it is assigned *before* any ordering is applied.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp, Oops! You are **absolutely correct**.  Despicable me.  ROWNUM is assigned *before* ordering, as you commented.  +1.

Comment: Of course, you *can* wrap the query as a subquery, then order by the rownum, e.g. select * from (select x, ROWNUM r from t) order by r;

Comment: Probably: select ROWNUM, firstname from (select firstname from t order by firstname)